# Как программно проскроллить RecyclerView до конца?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Имеется `RecyclerView` с динамической подгрузкой данных: при достижении предпоследнего элемента списка начинается загрузка следующих элементов.

Пусть пользователь проскроллил список до того состояния, когда на экране стал виден предпоследний элемент списка. Началась загрузка данных, при этом в конец списка добавился элемент с прогрессбаром.

Пусть в процессе загрузки данных пользователь проскроллил список до конца: на экране полностью видим элемент с прогрессбаром.

Если в процессе загрузки данных произошла ошибка, то элемент с прогрессбаром заменяется на элемент с сообщением об ошибке.

Элемент с сообщением об ошибке по высоте больше элемента с прогрессбаром. Тогда, при замене элемента с прогрессбаром на элемент с сообщением об ошибке, элемент с сообщением об ошибке виден не полностью.

После замены элемента с прогрессбаром на элемент с сообщением об ошибке требуется как-то программно проскроллить список до конца, чтобы элемент с ошибкой был полностью видим.

Что пробовал:

Раз:

```
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

Два:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
layoutManager.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

где `mAdapter` -- адаптер для `mRecyclerView`.

В этих вариантах не происходит никакого изменения состояния прокрутки.

Comment: Мало информации. Вы пытались использовать scrollTo(lastPosition) и у вас не получилосьь?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Обновил вопрос. Да, пробовал. Да, не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

```
mLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(yourList.size());
```

Comment: Нумерация элементов в адаптере начинается с нуля, следовательно, последний элемент списка имеет номер `yourList.size()-1`, в вашем варианте Вы пытаетесь проскроллить список к элементу с номером, которого не существует. Даже если `yourList.size()` заменить на `yourList.size()-1`, то ничего не происходит.